# How to round decimal to 3 decimal places?

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller

I have variable result. It contains each time different value. It is decimal number. How can i round or just show 3 decimal places?

Code:

```
var result = amount * exchangeRate1[fromCurrency] / exchangeRate2[toCurrency];
```

Comment: use: [Decimal.Round Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.round?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to SHOW 3 decimal places, you have to format value to string

```
 string val = Math.Round(result,3).ToString("0.000"); // 2.000
```

if you use just Round

```
result = Math.Round(result,3) // 2
```

it will be shown less then 3 decimal places, if your result has less than 3 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Math.Round(result, 3);
```